# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type error when pushing into array stored in object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to organize some event listeners in an object keyed by an enum. Each property may have a different function signature, but I would like to push event listeners to the array given the event name. Here's a rough idea of what I have right now:

```
type MessageListener = (event: MessageEvent) => void;
type CloseListener = (event: CloseEvent) => void;
type ErrorListener = (event: Event) => void;
type OpenListener = (event: Event) => void;
type OpeningListener = () => void;

export enum ListenerType {
  Message = 'message',
  Close = 'close',
  Open = 'open',
  Error = 'error',
  Opening = 'opening',
}

export interface Listeners {
  [ListenerType.Message]: MessageListener[];
  [ListenerType.Close]: CloseListener[];
  [ListenerType.Open]: OpenListener[];
  [ListenerType.Error]: ErrorListener[];
  [ListenerType.Opening]: OpeningListener[];
}
```

And then I have a function to add event listeners like this:

```
addEventListener(handlerName: ListenerType, handler: Listeners[ListenerType][number]) {
  if (handlerName in this.listeners) {
    this.listeners[handlerName].push(handler);
  }
}
```

But then I get the following error when trying to push `handler`:

```
Argument of type 'MessageListener[] | CloseListener[] | OpenListener[] | ErrorListener[] | OpeningListener[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OpeningListener'.
  Type 'MessageListener[]' is not assignable to type 'OpeningListener'.
    Type 'MessageListener[]' provides no match for the signature '(): void'.ts(2345
```

I guess the issue has to do with the function signatures being different for each listener type, but I'm curious if there's anyway to work around this without having to cast `handler as any`?

Comment: This would require some sort of correlated variable types which TS does not support. Just use an assertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a feature that hasn't been implemented yet :(

Correlated Types:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581